# Actuator Health Endpoint returns OUT_OF_SERVICE, when all groups are UP

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to set up readiness probe for my app deployed to k8s but under the `actuator/health` endpoint I am getting different status, comparing to `actuator/health/readiness` endpoint.

It's important, that this behaviour is only observed when the app is deployed to k8s cluster.

So without any additional config in the `application.properties` file I am getting:

```
➜  ~ curl localhost:8080/actuator/health
{"status":"OUT_OF_SERVICE","groups":["liveness","readiness"]}%
➜  ~ curl localhost:8080/actuator/health/liveness
{"status":"UP"}%
➜  ~ curl localhost:8080/actuator/health/readiness
{"status":"OUT_OF_SERVICE"}%
```

Which seems to be correct - if the readiness state is `OUT_OF_SERVICE`, the health endpoint returns `OUT_OF_SERVICE` as well, because it includes `readiness` group. This is at least consistent.

On the other hand, when I specify what should be included in the `readiness` group in the `application.properties` file it seems to be reporting inconsistent results. In my case I've added one entry to my configuration file, which is: `management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include=ping`

This time that's what I have as a result of sending the same set of requests as before:

```
➜  ~ curl localhost:8080/actuator/health
{"status":"OUT_OF_SERVICE","groups":["liveness","readiness"]}%
➜  ~ curl localhost:8080/actuator/health/liveness
{"status":"UP"}%
➜  ~ curl localhost:8080/actuator/health/readiness
{"status":"UP"}%
```

This is inconsistent - when both `liveness` and `readiness` endpoint return status `UP` I'd expect to see the same status in the `health` endpoint.

I am looking for an explanation what I have misconfigured here, and why it works that way.

To make it easier, I've created a small app, where you can verify this behaviour on your cluster:
https://github.com/gebertdominik/actuator-bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.x/reference/htmlsingle/#features.spring-application.application-availability.readiness), the application is not ready to handle traffic until application and command-line runners have been called. Your command-line runner that calls your `EventConsumer` never returns so the application is never considered ready to handle traffic.

It's easier to see the effect that this has if you configure the health endpoint to always show details:

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

The health endpoint now shows all of the individual components that are aggregated to produce the overall health:

```
{
    "components": {
        "diskSpace": {
            "details": {
                "exists": true,
                "free": 465064448000,
                "threshold": 10485760,
                "total": 1000240963584
            },
            "status": "UP"
        },
        "livenessState": {
            "status": "UP"
        },
        "ping": {
            "status": "UP"
        },
        "readinessState": {
            "status": "OUT_OF_SERVICE"
        }
    },
    "groups": [
        "liveness",
        "readiness"
    ],
    "status": "OUT_OF_SERVICE"
}
```

`OUT_OF_SERVICE` is returned due to the status of the `readinessState` component.

In its default configuration, `readinessState` is used by the `readiness` group and it too returns `OUT_OF_SERVICE`. By setting `management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include=ping`, you have created your own custom `readiness` group that only includes the `ping` component. It now returns `UP`, which is consistent with the status of the `ping` component in the overall health response. As [shown in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.x/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.endpoints.kubernetes-probes.external-state) you should include `readinessState` when customizing the `readinessGroup`:

```
management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include=readinessState,ping
```

Comment: But how does it explain different statuses for `health` and `health/readiness` endpoints?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain the behaviour when you configure `readiness.include`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It seems to be clear now, and what I understand, `CommandLineRunner` should not be used for endless tasks like consuming messages etc.

Comment: This became the lesson of the day for me. Someone never should run endless tasks in CommandLineRunner or ApplicationListener. I solved this problem by running my endless task in another thread using a Single Threaded ExecutorService.